# create own Listener in android

Tags: java, android, interface, listener

i want to add listener to my class below :

```
    class BitmapDisplay implements Runnable
    {
        IAsyncFetchListener fetchListener = null;
        public void setListener(IAsyncFetchListener listener) {
            this.fetchListener = listener;
        }
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BitmapToLoad bitmapToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplay(Bitmap b, BitmapToLoad p){bitmap=b;bitmapToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
            returnbitmap=bitmap;
            else
            returnbitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), stub_id);

            this.fetchListener.onComplete(returnbitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

but my listener wont work in eclipse

```
imageLoader.DisplayBitmap("").setListener(new IAsyncFetchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bitmap bitmap) {
        photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
});
```

I get an error in setListener :

> The method setListener(new IAsyncFetchListener(){}) is undefined for
>   the type Bitmap" how to solve it?

Comment: my interface is :public interface IAsyncFetchListener {
        void onComplete(Bitmap bitmap);
}

Comment: check my edited ans I think it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do `imageLoader.DisplayBitmap("")`, the method `DisplayBitmap("")` return a `Bitmap`.

You are mixing the method `DisplayBitmap` with the object `BitmapDisplay`.

But you can be able to do that :

```
BitmapDisplay bd=new BitmapDisplay(bmp, bitmapToLoad);
bd.setListener(new IAsyncFetchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bitmap bitmap) {
                photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
          }
);
```

Comment: but i remove return value from DisplayBitmap("") not solve it?!

Comment: Well your method public Bitmap DisplayBitmap(String url); still return a Bitmap. You need to set the Listener to your object BitmapDisplay.

Comment: BitmapDisplay not public  my class only with DisplayBitmap(""), i want add listener on it please show my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following:

**DisplayBitmap function**

```
public Void DisplayBitmap(String url,IAsyncFetchListener listener)
{
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        listener.onComplete(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queueBitmap(url,listener);
        listener.onComplete(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), stub_id));
    }
}
```

**queueBitmap function**

```
private void queueBitmap(String url,IAsyncFetchListener listener)
{
    BitmapToLoad p=new BitmapToLoad(url);
    executorService.submit(new BitmapsLoader(p,listener));
}
```

**BitmapsLoader constructor**

```
 IAsyncFetchListener listener;
 BitmapsLoader(BitmapToLoad bitmapToLoad,IAsyncFetchListener listener){
        this.bitmapToLoad=bitmapToLoad;
        this.listener=listener;
 }
```

**Run method**

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(bitmapToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(bitmapToLoad.url, bmp);
            BitmapDisplay bd=new BitmapDisplay(bmp, bitmapToLoad);
            bd.setListener(listener);
            handler.post(bd);
            }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And finally call this:

```
imageLoader.DisplayBitmap("",new IAsyncFetchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bitmap bitmap) {
       photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
});
```

Comment: you r codes work only     Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        listener.onComplete(bitmap); and dont send oncomplete in BitmapDisplay

Comment: I think by the time bitmap is loaded photoView reference is changed.

Comment: bitmapdisplay not send oncomplete whay? please help me plase?

Comment: Try to check if oncomplete is even getting called

Comment: i check codes and i underestand oncomplete is send (i changed code and send listener to BitmapDisplay) but when i Running back tandem Code imageLoader.DisplayBitmap("",new IAsyncFetchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bitmap bitmap) {
       photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}); then one tocomplete recive?!why?